# Why is React not able to resolve the module for my imports?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to import these files from different folders in my project folder, but react keeps giving me an error, Unable to resolve "../../../hook/useFetch" from "components\home\nearby\Nearbyjobs.jsx" it then says none of these folders exist, but I have them downloaded in the same project folder.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import {Stack, useRouter } from 'expo-router';

import {COLORS, icons, images, SIZES } from '../constants';
import {
    Nearbyjobs, Popularjobs, ScreenHeaderBtn, Welcome
} from '../components' 

const Home = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite}}>
            <Stack.Screen
            options={{
                headerStyle: { backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite}, 
                headerShadowVisible: false,
                headerLeft: () => (
                    <ScreenHeaderBtn iconurl = {icons.menu} dimension ="60%" />
                ),
                headerRight: () => (
                    <ScreenHeaderBtn iconurl = {icons.profile} dimension ="100%" />
                ),
            }}
            />


        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
export default Home
```

Above is my code, and all I am trying to do is run the app.

Comment: if you are watching the video from JavaScrpit Mastery chanel wich i think you are i think you have downloaded the finished version of the code from github thats why you get Unable to resolve "../../../hook/useFetch since you havent created that hook yet the link you have to download in order to get the starter files is this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VGr3R-3uta9xNj17eRHMxTELhtE2LaCm/view)